# WordPress translation placeholders

Tags: wordpress, translation, gettext, poedit, po

So, I want to translate a WordPress theme and plugin using POEDIT.
There are some strings that use placeholders like %s and %d, can someone tell me what exactly they stand for?

Because, for example I have "%d Adult" and "%s Adult" but I dont know whats the difference between them

Comment: `%d` = Integer, `%s` = String - [Read here](http://php.net/manual/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 1):

Those placeholders are part of the format specification for [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

In short, this function takes a 'format string' and then a series of values and creates a new string with the provided values inserted into format string:

```
$verse = sprintf('%d bottles of %s on the wall', 99, 'beer');
```

The `%d` placeholder indicates that it's a spot for signed decimal integer.
The `%s` placeholder indicates that it's a spot for a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$wpdb->prepare() supports a small subset of the sprintf() arguments. 
        The %d is a placeholder for an integer (not a decimal, that would be %f).
        Use %d when you want to send a real integer to the database,
        Use %s for strings.
```